# How to use rails with both disable_with and client_side_validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, client-side-validation

I am using Rails 3.2.8 and the excellent client_side_validations gem and would also like to use the rails disable_with option on my submitbutton on a form. Problem is, client_side_validations is not run until the user clicks the submitbutton and if there are input errors (i.e. an inputfield left blank by accident), rails by then has already disabled the submitbutton because the user clicked submit, meaning the user cannot submit the form after correcting the errors.

Does anybody have a good solution?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgrade to the 3.2 version of ClientSideValidations I have just released it now supports `:disable_with`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you for pointing me to the new release and thank you *so* much for all the work with client_side_validations. Absolutely one of the best gems for Rails out there. Thank you :-)